# CSV File Row Aggregation with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have CSV file that looks like this:

```
State, name, balans
OH, John, 345
OH, Bill, 281
IL, James, 34
OH, James, 45
MA, Bill, 71
OH, Thomas, 541 
SC, Pete, 125
AL, Mary, 51
NY, Ivan, 123
MD, Chan, 234
CA, Lee, 181
WI, Juan, 131
AL, Kate, 135
CO, Robert, 215
```

I need to get total balances aggregated by state.

So that output file.txt, would look like this:

```
OH [Sum of balans]   
NY [sum of ballans]
etc
```

I was looking on the internet for such example but didn't find anything. I need some code example or framework, I could work with.

I thought I should be doing something like this:

```
$inputfile  = 'input.csv';

$outputFile = 'output.txt';


$inputHandle = fopen($inputfile, "r");
$outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
$balansCol = 2;

while (($dataRow = fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $sumArray = array();
    $sumArray[] = $dataRow;      
 }

   foreach ($sumArray as  $subArray) {

    foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
        $sumArray[2] += $value;
    }
}
```

But I think this is not good approach... Could someone provide some relatively simple method to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it (tested, you'll have to modify the outputs) and should get you started:

```
$csv = <<< ENDL
OH, John, 345
OH, Bill, 281
IL, James, 34
OH, James, 45
MA, Bill, 71
OH, Thomas, 541 
SC, Pete, 125
AL, Mary, 51
NY, Ivan, 123
MD, Chan, 234
CA, Lee, 181
WI, Juan, 131
AL, Kate, 135
CO, Robert, 215 
ENDL;

$csv = explode("\n", $csv); // using this instead of file("file.csv");
$output = array();
foreach($csv as $line) {
    list($state, $name, $count) = str_getcsv($line);
    $state = trim($state);
    $name  = trim($name);
    $count = trim($count);
    $output[$state] += (int)$count;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($output);
/**
Outputs:
array(10) {
  ["OH"]=>
  int(0)
  ["IL"]=>
  int(0)
  ["MA"]=>
  int(0)
  ["SC"]=>
  int(0)
  ["AL"]=>
  int(0)
  ["NY"]=>
  int(0)
  ["MD"]=>
  int(0)
  ["CA"]=>
  int(0)
  ["WI"]=>
  int(0)
  ["CO"]=>
  int(0)
}
**/
```

PS: may not be the best solution for massive files.

Answer (score 0):

No need for subarrays and more than one iteration. Create empty array for sums and fill it creating / adding elements while looping through file:

```
$sumArray = array();
while (($dataRow = fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $state = $dataRow[0];
    $balance =  $dataRow[2];
    if (!isset($sumArray[$state])) {
        $sumArray[$state] = 0; // create new entry for state with balance=0
    }
    $sumArray[$state] += $balance; // add balance for state
}
```

Comment: could u explain the logic here?

Comment: `$dataRow[0]` is State from your CSV, used as index of sum array. Resulting array will look like `$sumArray = array('OH' => 1520, 'NY' => 2409);`

Comment: Edited question to make it look more clearly. Also please get familiar with very basics like array structures. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Could you explain why $sumArray[$state] is actually $balance? Isn't that a value for 'state?'